# Why does OpenJPA not store foreign keys by default?

Tags: java, database, openjpa

By default OpenJPA does not create foreign keys for database tables, which surprised me. The [official statement](http://openjpa.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-WhyOpenJPAisnotcreatingforeignkeyconstraintsonthedatabasetables%253F) on the "why" does not even touch upon the why, it simply explains what to do in order to change the default setup. I know there is a performance penalty for constraint checking, but is it only me thinking that clean structure should supersede performance in a default setup? Does someone know more about the why? I could not find any more official statements.

Comment: According to the link you provided, you can change the behaviour. So, where is the problem?

Comment: There should be a good reason for the decision. It's not a problem, it's a question (see faq about questions, e.g. bullet 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon a similar issue related to foreign key constraint handling in OpenJPA. Please have a look at the [OpenJPA forum discussion](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Constraint-violation-using-OneToOne-relationship-td6978223.html) about it. Kevin Sutter has some answers. Maybe they satisfy your need for more information.

Comment: Thank you mwalter. From what I understand the reason is purely that OpenJPA has problems with insertion/deletion orders when foreign keys are enforced. If that is the real reason for the default setup, this should  be mentioned on the "why" page.